# How to call laws that is there to regulate journalism and media

Tags: single-word-requests

There are certain laws that regulate journalism and media. For example, there are laws to the effect that journalism should be truthful--which is sometimes called truth-in-advertisement law.

Is there any name that covers all such laws, or we can simply say "journalism laws"?

For example, what to put in the following blank?

> All these news channels are monitored by ... .

Comment: What laws are you talking about? Can you provide one? And in which country?

Comment: @Clare I already mentioned one: truth in advertisement law is another name for it.

Comment: No you did not mention "truth in advertisement law" in your question.

Comment: Laws are not created to align with certain professions. Laws such as defamation, libel and slandour are more pertinent to journalism, as their broadcasting ability can magnify actions in this area. I see truth in advertising as consumer law, affecting ad creators rahther than journalists

Comment: Truth in advertising is a business law. It has little to do with journalism.

Answer (score 2):

> **[Media Law](https://www.hg.org/media.html)** is a legal field that relates to legal regulation of the telecommunications industry, information technology, broadcasting, advertising, the entertainment industry, censorship, and internet and online services among others.